# Deadlock with ExternalTaskOperators: Why, how often, and how to get around that problem?

Tags: deadlock, airflow

I am implementing scheduled pipelines and currently I am using an `ExternalTaskOperator` to set inter-DAG dependency. I read [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls) that if you don't manually raise the priority of the upstream tasks it's possible that there will be deadlock.

I was wondering how common this situation is, how you manually raise priority levels of different tasks (the source code of many, like Bash and Python Operators, don't seem to have a `priority_level` param), and if there are any other better methods of setting inter-DAG dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used `ExternalTaskSensor` in production, so can't comment on *how often* deadlocks occur. But apart from [`priority_weight` / `weight_rule`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L124) that you already mentioned, I can think of 2 more ways to *try to* overcome this

- Using [Airflow `pool`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510574/3679900) to guarantee dedicated slots for sets tasks
- Using [`mode` param](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator.py#L46) of `Sensor`s (`BaseSensorOperator`)