# Conditionally execute multiple branches one by one

Tags: airflow

**Note**

- Please read and understand the question thoroughly
- It cannot be solved by simple [`BranchPythonOperator`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/python_operator.html#BranchPythonOperator) / [`ShortCircuitOperator`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/python_operator.html#ShortCircuitOperator)

---

We have an unusual [multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer)-like use-case in our workflow

```
                                +-----------------------+
                                |                       |
                  +------------>+  branch-1.begin-task  |
                  |             |                       |
                  |             +-----------------------+
                  |
                  |
                  |             +-----------------------+
                  |             |                       |
                  +------------>+  branch-2.begin-task  |
                  |             |                       |
+------------+    |             +-----------------------+
|            |    |
|  MUX-task  +----+                         +
|            |    |                         |
+------------+    |
                  |                         |
                  +- -- -- -- ->
                  |                         |
                  |
                  |                         |
                  |                         +
                  |
                  |             +-----------------------+
                  |             |                       |
                  +------------>+  branch-n.begin-task  |
                                |                       |
                                +-----------------------+
```

---

The flow is expected to work as follows

- `MUX-task` listens for **events on an external queue** (single queue)
- each event on queue triggers execution of *one of the branches* (branch-n.begin-task)
- one-by-one, as events arrive, the MUX-task must **trigger execution of respective branch**
- once all branches have been triggered, the MUX-task completes

**Assumptions**

- Exactly `n` events arrive on queue, one for triggering each branch
- `n` is *dynamically-known*: it's value is defined in a [`Variable`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/concepts.html#variables)

**Limitations**

- The external queue where events arrive is **only one**
- we can't have `n` queues (one per branch) since branches grow with time (n is dynamically defined)

---

We are not able to come up with a solution within Airflow's set of [operators and sensors](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/concepts.html#operators) (or any such thing available out-of-the-hood in `Airflow`) to build this

1. `Sensor`s can be used for listening events on external queue; but we have to listen for multiple events, not one
2. [`BranchPythonOperator`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.BranchPythonOperator) can be used to trigger execution of a single branch out of many, but it immediately [marks remaining branches as skipped](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python.py#L164)

**Primary bottleneck**

Because of the 2nd limitation above, even a custom-operator combining functionality of a `Sensor` and `BranchPythonOperator` won't work.

We have tried to brainstorm around a fancy combination of `Sensors`, `DummyOperator` and [`trigger_rules`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43680277/3679900) to achieve this, but have had no success thus far.

Is this doable in Airflow?

---

**UPDATE-1**

Here's some background info to understand the context of workflow

- we have an ETL pipeline to sync `MySQL` tables (across multiple `Aurora` databases) to our data-lake
- to overcome the impact of our sync pipeline on production databases, we have decided to do this

  - for each database, create a **snapshot** ([restore `AuroraDB` cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html) from last backup)
  - run `MySQL` sync pipeline using that *snapshot*
  - at then end of sync, terminate the *snapshot* (`AuroraDB` cluster)
- the [snapshot lifecycle events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-cloud-watch-events.html) of `Aurora` snapshot *restore process* are published to an `SQS` queue

  - single queue for all databases
  - this setup was done by our DevOps team (different AWS account, we don't have access to the underlying `Lambda`s / `SQS` / infra)

Answer (score 0):

`XCOM`s to the rescue!

---

We decided to model the tasks as follows (both tasks are *custom* `operator`s)

- The `MUX-task` is more like an **iterative-`sensor`**: it keeps listening for events on queue and takes some action against each event arriving on queue
- All `branch-x.begin-task`s are **simple sensors**: they listen for publishing of an `XCOM` (who's name is in a *pre-defined specific format*)

---

The workflow runs as follows

- The `MUX-task` listens for events on queue (listening part is enclosed in a **`for`-loop** with as many iterations as the number of branches)
- When an event arrives, the `MUX-task` picks it up; it **identifies which 'branch' should be triggered and publishes an `XCOM`** for the respective branch
- The respective **branch's `sensor` picks up that `XCOM`** on it's next poke and the branch starts executing. In effect, *branch's `sensor` merely acts as a **gateway*** that opens up with an external event (`XCOM`) and allows execution of branch

Since there are too many sensors (one per branch), we would most likely be [employing `mode='reschedule'`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator/index.html) to overcome [deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510574/3679900)

---

- Since the described approach relies heavily on **polling**, we don't deem it to be super efficient.
- A **reactive triggering** based approach would be more desirable, but we haven't been able to work it out

---

**UPDATE-1**

- Looks like 'reactive' approach is achievable if we could model **each branch as a separate `DAG`** and instead of publishing `XCOM`s for each branch, trigger the branch's `DAG` just like **`TriggerDagRunOperator`** does
- But since our *monolithic `DAG`* is generated *programmatically* via complex logic, this change would have been quite hard (lots of code rewrite). So we decided to continue with the *poll-based approach* and live with few minutes of extra delay in a pipeline that already takes several hours to complete

---

**UPDATE-2**

*[with reference to **UPDATE-1** section of question]*

Since our actual implementation required us to just wait for creation of database, we decided to simplify the workflow as follows

- database endpoints were fixed via `DNS` (they didn't *change* every time `Aurora` snapshot was restored)
- we did away with the `MUX-task` (and so also the `SQS` queue for *Aurora restore lifecycle events*)
- each branch's begin-task `branch-x.begin-task` was modelled as a **simple `sensor`** that tried firing a *dummy* SQL query (`SELECT 1`) to check if database endpoint has become active or not